# Concatenation of two strings fails in ruby (why a new line?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a wired problem. I tried to concatenate two strings. If I do this with @Client.ip I get a string with a new line. @Client.ip is a string.

I used this:

```
order= "net rpc shutdown #{ip} --user=administrator%***! --timeout=100 --force -C 'bla'"
```

or this

```
order= "net rpc shutdown "+ @client.ip + " --user=administrator%*** --timeout=100 --force -C 'bla'"
```

The result is this:

```
net rpc shutdown 178.213.111.69
  --user=administrator%*** --timeout=100 --force -C 'bla'
```

If I write the ip manually and concatenate it then, it works fine and everything is in one line .... Why is that happening? Has someone an idea? :-) I need this string in one line to use the system(-) command.

Comment: Where is `@client.ip` coming from? Sounds like it is adding a newline.

Comment: what is the value of @client.ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `@client.ip` has a newline at the end of it. Try striping it out

```
order= "net rpc shutdown #{@client.ip.rstrip} --user=administrator%*** --timeout=100 --force -C 'bla'"
```

[`String#rstrip`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/String/rstrip) will remove any whitespace at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [chomp helper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp) for string class

```
order= "net rpc shutdown #{ip.chomp} --user=administrator%***! --timeout=100 --force -C 'bla'"
```